# Hive get mimimum of two values for where clause

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to write a hive query such that i need to use a date based where clause to filter on records.

```sql
WHERE date_key 
BETWEEN date_sub(current_date, 4) 
  AND MINIMUM(date_sub(current_date, 1), to_date("2018-10-14"))
```

Can we do something like `MINIMUM` of two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using oracle then there is a keyword called "least" which will output the lesser of values. 
Eg:

```
WHERE date_key 
BETWEEN date_sub(current_date, 4) 
  AND LEAST(date_sub(current_date, 1), to_date("2018-10-14"))
```

Otherwise you can handcraft the query to compare the two values as follows

```
WHERE date_key 
BETWEEN date_sub(current_date, 4) 
  AND (CASE WHEN date_sub(current_date, 1)< to_date("2018-10-14") THEN 
                 date_sub(current_date, 1)
            ELSE to_date("2018-10-14")
        END)
```

Comment: the first approach is better. i would suggest not using `case` expressions in `where`. btw..`least` works with Hive too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother.  Just write:

```
WHERE date_key >= date_sub(current_date, 4) AND
      date_key <= date_sub(current_date, 1) AND
      date_key <= to_date('2018-10-14')
```

If something is less than the minimum of two values, then it is less than each of the values.